# select sal from emp order by sal desc limit 1,1;

Tags: sql

```
select sal from emp order by sal desc limit 1,1;
```

SQL command not properly ended GIVES ERROR

I wan´t to get the employee with the NTH highest salary in each department.

I´m using SQL.

Comment: WHich dbms are you using? (LIMIT is a product specific feature.)

Comment: Note that SQL is a _language_, implemented by dozens of products.

Comment: Also, what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ANSI syntax `offset ... fetch ...`:

```
select sal from emp order by sal desc offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find it useful [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

but you will need `group by` if you need it by section

```markdown
  select 
    department,
    max(sal) 
  from emp 
  group by department
```